# Flutter Carouse Pro Zoom

Tags: flutter

I have the below carousel (using the carousel pro package) can I made zoomable images, all images are received from network

```
SizedBox(
                    height: 280.0,
                    width: 380.0,
                    child: 
                    Carousel(
                      images: [
                       for(final image in imagesPosts[i]) ...[
                          NetworkImage(_urlImages+posts[i]['userid']+"/"+image),
                          //Text(image),

                       ],
                      ],
                      dotSize: 4.0,
                      dotSpacing: 15.0,
                      dotColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                      indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
                      dotBgColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                      borderRadius: true,
                      autoplay: false,
                      //animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,

                    ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final pictures;

  const DetailsPage(
      {Key key,      
      this.pictures})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailsPageState createState() => _DetailsPageState();
}

class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  bool isImageTapped = false;
  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget imageCarousel = Container(
      height: 200,
      child: Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        images: widget.pictures ,
        onImageTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
            this.isImageTapped = true;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(          
          body: isImageTapped
              ? GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    child: widget.pictures[this.index],
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      this.index=0;
                      this.isImageTapped = false;
                    });
                  },
                )
              : ListView(
                  children: [                   
                    imageCarousel,               
                  ],
                )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InteractiveViewer` Widget just wrap your carousel image inside **InteractiveViewer** and pass the `scaleEnabled` param as 'True'.

```
InteractiveViewer(
        scaleEnabled: true,
        yourImageWidgetHere: ...,
 )
```

[here is the sample example from flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html)